# Install4j8 handling of empty search Sequence changed

Tags: java, install4j

We have to make sure our product launches with the java we included in the install4j Setup.
In install4j 7 we did this by clearing the JRE Search Sequence and it worked.
But with install4j 8 it seems to delete empty search sequence blocks out of the .install4j file when you save it and use the default JRE Search Sequence of JRE_HOME and JDK_HOME.
If you open an .install4j File with an empty search sequence block in Install4j 8 it is shown in the UI as empty but after a save with Install4j 8 and reopen the default is shown.
We found a workaround by putting only the directory of our included JRE in the JRE Search Sequence.
It seems like a bug because in [Install4j Java minimum version seems not functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511024/install4j-java-minimum-version-seems-not-functional) the soulution we used for Install4j 7 was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a regression in install4j 8, it will be fixed in 8.0.6. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build where this is already fixed.

Comment: is there a planned release date for install4j 8.0.6?

Comment: It's probably not to far off, maybe a couple of weeks. Sorry that I cannot be more precise.